# [facebook app]Is there any way I can get the user_id from tab?

Tags: facebook-iframe

I'm trying to get user_id from the tab.
I found out the params["signed_request"] will give me some info about the user_id.
And I tried.
But, in fact , params["signed_request"]  gave me the wrong value.
It returned the profile_id instead of user_id.
Is there anyway I can get the user_id from tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a user's ID after they have interacted with the tab.